# For loop Error Expected Identifier or '('

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

The compiler is giving me an error when I try to make a for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { //Expected identifier or '(', highlights the word for
NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is the code that comes before it:

```
#import "editCodeTable.h"

@implementation editCodeTable

NSArray *languages;

NSArray *everything;
```

Comment: What is the code that comes before this? Post the whole method/function.

Comment: "Xcode is giving me an error" - no, it doesn't. The compiler does. This question is unrelated to Xcode.

Comment: @H2CO3 You beat me too it.

Comment: @Undo I always watch them.

Comment: If that is literally the code that comes before it, you need your for loop in a method or function. Is it just hanging out under the @implementation?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your for-loop.  If those are the only lines of code in your file, then you are not putting that loop within a method so the compiler is all confused.  What is your goal here?  Are you writing a Mac or iOS application?  Is this intended to be a class?  Or what?

Comment: This is the code that I added before this. I'm making a mac application right now, but I've managed to fix this.

Comment: I'm almost tempted to give you a +1 for actually quoting the error, vs just saying that "for loop doesn't work".  But as it is it just cancels out you cluelessness otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be confused as to how to program in general... you can't have code just lingering around all "willy-nilly".  You need to place the for-loop within an appropriate method or function.

For example, I think you are doing this (if I understand you correctly):

```
#import "editCodeTable.h"

@implementation editCodeTable

NSArray *languages;

NSArray *everything;

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { //Error here!
    NSLog(@"Test");
}

@end
```

You need to put your code within a method or function, and then call the method/function wherever you want it to print the test.  For example you could do something like this:

```
#import "editCodeTable.h"

@implementation editCodeTable

NSArray *languages;

NSArray *everything;

void printTest() //This is a C function -> C code is perfectly 
                 //acceptable in Objective-C
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Test");
    }
}

//Or you could do this:

- (void) printOutTest //This is an Objective-C method
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Test");
    }
}

@end
```

Consult an [Objective-C guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/) or reference book for more information.  You cannot just place code wherever you please.  You need to organize it according to the appropriate syntax.  Without more information about your end goal, however, I cannot give you a more specific answer to what you need done in your instance.

Comment: Well, this isn't a method, it's a function (which is what Carl was asking about).

Comment: I updated my post, does that help at all Carl?

Comment: Yeah it was me being an idiot, my apologies.

Comment: Its cool.  I've done sillier things (and likely will do more) :D

Comment: Thank you so much. Instead of making fun of my mistake (which was bad, but I'm learning Objective-C through my knowledge of both C and by learning Cocoa), you told me what I did wrong.

Comment: Glad I could help :)  Please press the check mark button to "Accept" this answer so that others know that your question has been answered.